# Boot-repair Failure: Unable to locate package grub-common:i386

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

I am on a system dual-booting Windows and Debian (usually using the latter), and a recent Windows update appears to have wreaked havoc on the Debian boot system. I managed to boot Windows again, but not Linux. Following online suggestions, I created a Live USB of Ubuntu, and booted from that. Then I have installed and run the boot-repair utility. The utility instructs me to type several lines including

```
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda6" apt-get purge -y grub*-common grub-common:i386
```

To which I receive the error

```
E: Unable to locate package grub-common:i386
```

I am given to understand the issue may have to do with having UEFI vs BIOS (I believe I have UEFI), but do not understand this well. In any case I have subsequently run the boot-repair BootInfo Summary utility which created the following file http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/N8Z95MwB9p/

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue with boot-repair / the boot system would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

--Edit--
In what was probably an ill-advised move, I decided to try once again to solve the issue using online resources. From a Linux live disk I ran the following sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda I cancelled the second command partway through with CTRL-C when I saw it was trying to install i386 version. Here is a new pastebin, which I believe to be different (and worse..) than the previous one. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZpCm38wmRc/

Comment: Regardless of whether you are using Ubuntu or Debian, purging `grub-common` is a bad idea.   Probably you want to run something like `sudo grub-install /dev/sda ; sudo update-grub`.